# Debugging for MS Edge constant reload - how to trigger debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, microsoft-edge

I am debugging some code on the MS Edge browser, but it reloaded twice and showed a "This page is having a problem loading" message after two tries. The page has been tested on IE11 or lower, Chrome, and Firefox with no issues.

I have been having trouble bringing up the debugger during page execution by placing the debugger statement in various parts of the code. I have placed it in the first line of the script in the body tag, I have placed it in the first line of $(document).ready(); and even in the script tag in the header. I am so surprised when none of the debuggers triggered other than the one in IE11 (both Chrome and Firefox did not trigger either). Edge of course still continued on its reload loop and saying that it has a problem loading.

My question is - am I not doing this right? Is there a list of when a debugger; statement will not trigger? And more importantly, how do I trigger it in Edge before it reloads twice and throw the error page (For reference, pulling up F12 after it throws the error page gives the DOM of the error page, which is not helpful.)

Comment: if the page won't load, you can't debug it - because there's nothing to debug if the page doesn't load

Comment: But by placing the debugger at the first line of the script tag, am I not effectively asking it to start the debugger before the page even loads completely?

Comment: depends ... you need to know why the page is not loading ... could be nothing to do with javascript

Comment: I do see some of the DOM elements got loaded in MS Edge before the page ran into its reload cycle. Based on that, would it be safe to say that the page actually did load? If that is not true, how can I confirm that it is not a loading issue not related to JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Edge where the console seems to crash along with the browser. I have noticed it numerous times during development and have not been able to find a solution.

Check in every other browser on an empty cache and see if you are getting any errors in console. Older versions of Edge, before the last service pack were very flakey so I would suggest making sure your environment is upto date.